# If a web crawler get a 404 error, will it not index that url?

Tags: html, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, 404, server

Say I have a page `page.example.com/page`. In my (python) server, you only get served html if you are logged in, which you can do at `page.example.com/login`. If you aren't logged in, the server responds with a 404 error.

Does this mean that web-crawlers would be unable to index this page? Or, more accurately, they wouldn't index it, because it "doesn't exist".

Comment: if you don't make any link to this page they won't find it nor index it.

Comment: So no links + 404 will do the noindex trick?

Comment: The only page that won't raise 404 will be the login page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Googlebot see 404 HTTP status code then they don't index that page at all. It will even remove the indexed pages if they continue to see 404 status  for a long time. So hope you understand how Google seriously see 404 status code.

You should add functionality like quora, they allowed to view n number of pages before they force user to logged in.  Google called it [first click free](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/40543?hl=en), but now it's called [flexible sampling](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7532484)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I might do that, but not on this site - invite only.